# Distance between related, but separate math terms

Tags: spacing

Say I have two equations that I would like to have in display math, `a_1 = 1` and `a_2 = 2`. If I just put them like this, they do not look separated enough:

```
\[ a_1 = 1, a_2 = 2 \]
```

I usually use `,\quad` for separation, but that looks wider than any spacing I have in the remaining document.

What is the correct spacing to convey this sort of list?

Comment: Most style guides (Oxford, Byrd Press and [AMS](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/author-info/documentation/howto/mit-2.pdf#page=52)) recommend a double quad to separate two equations on the same line. Note that you should type `{,}\qquad` instead of `,\qquad` to avoid a spurious thin space.

Comment: Okay, that sounds canonical. Do you know about German standards?

Comment: No, but this kind of thing does vary from country to country and from style guide to style guide (e.g. the Almqvist & Wiksells style guide (from Sweden; they were the publishers of Acta Mathematica) says to use a quad).

Answer (score 3):

You may use a thin space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[ a_1 = 1,  a_2 = 2 \]‎
\[ a_1 = 1, \, a_2 = 2 \]‎
\[ a_1 = 1, \quad a_2 = 2 \]‎
\end{document}
```

[image]

If it were a display equation `\quad` looks decent, IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes I use `align` or `align*`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*} a_1 &= 1, & a_2 &= 2 \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can fine tune the spacing in a math environment using `\mspace{...}` where the units must be `mu`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[ a_1 = 1,  a_2 = 2 \]‎
\[ a_1 = 1, \mspace{5mu} a_2 = 2 \]‎
\[ a_1 = 1, \mspace{10mu} a_2 = 2 \]‎
\[ a_1 = 1, \mspace{15mu} a_2 = 2 \]‎
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: True, but also normal `\hspace` commands can be used; 18mu correspond to a quad in the math symbols font.